# trim ';' and split by ":"

Tags: linux, shell

I need to read a file like

```
#sys_platform:top_agent_id:channel
#              2       :    999     : 999
2:10086:10086;
2:999:999;
```

how to read sys_platform and top_agent_id, channel line by line

I write a shell , but not correctly

```
#!/bin/sh
sys_platform=""
top_agent_id=
channel=""

while read p; do 
    echo "line=$p"
    echo $p | awk -F ':' '{print $1 $2 $3}' | read sys_platform top_agent_id channel
    echo "sys_platform:${sys_platform}"
    echo "top_agent_id:${top_agent_id}"
done < ./channellist.txt
```

result as :

```
line=#sys_platform:top_agent_id:channel
sys_platform:
top_agent_id:
line=#              2       :    999     : 999
sys_platform:
top_agent_id:
line=2:10086:10086;
sys_platform:
top_agent_id:
line=2:999:999;
sys_platform:
top_agent_id:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` is your friend:

```
while read p; do 
    sys_platform=`echo $p | awk -F ':' '{print $1}'`
    top_agent_id=`echo $p | awk -F ':' '{print $2}'`
    channel=`echo $p | awk -F ':' '{print $3}' | tr -d ';'`
done < $filename
```

Nevertheless, you can do it directly with bash `set` builtin:

```
while read p; do
  OFS=$IFS
  IFS=':'
  set -f
  splitted=( $p )
  set +f
  sys_platform="${splitted[0]}"
  top_agent_id="${splitted[1]}"
  channel="${splitted[2]}"
  IFS=$OFS
done < $filename
```

Less readable but should be more efficient.